# Error in creation of bean while using @Required and @Autowired

Tags: java, spring

I am new to spring.I am trying to make use `@Required` and `@Autowired` in my code but its giving me `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException`.Below is my code.
1) StudentAuto.java

```
public class StudentAuto
{

@Autowired
private String name;
@Autowired
private  String city;
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
@Required
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

2)spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
<bean id='stu' class='com.bean.StudentAuto' >
</bean>

<bean name='name' class='java.lang.String'>
 <constructor-arg value="nm"></constructor-arg> 
 </bean> 

<bean name='city' class='java.lang.String'>
<constructor-arg value="ci"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
</beans>
```

3)TestApp.java

```
public class TestApp {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
StudentAuto auto=context.getBean("stu", StudentAuto.class);
System.out.println(auto.getCity());
System.out.println(auto.getName());
    }
}
```

and error stack trace is below.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stu' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Property 'city' is required for bean 'stu'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1079)
    at com.bean.TestApp.main(TestApp.java:14)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Property 'city' is required for bean 'stu'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    ... 7 more
```

Please help me on this issue.

Comment: `Property 'city' is required for bean 'stu'`

Comment: Why are you specifying `@Required`, and why are you putting it on a different member than the `@Autowired`? `@Autowired` defaults to required; just remove the `@Required` annotation.

Comment: Also, if you're new to Spring, I advise learning the JavaConfig system instead of the XML configuration. IMO, it's much cleaner and easier to work with.

Comment: Why don't you have a constructor with city?

Comment: @chrylis can't we use both `@Required` and `@Autowired` same time ?

Comment: There is no point in using `@Required` and `@Autowired` at the same time: `@Autowired` will cause an exception if the property cannot be set. Adding `@Required` just makes more work for the other, independent mechanism, which goes through the beans and checks the requirements are met.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik...So i have to use either `@Autowired` or `@Required` to check if property is set or not.

Comment: If you use `@Autowired` then the property is set, full stop. You do not need to check if it is set because it definitely is set by the virtue of being an `@Autowired` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javadoc for `@Required` states

> Marks a method (typically a JavaBean setter method) as being
>   'required': that is, the setter method must be configured to be
>   dependency-injected with a value.

Note that the annotated method is not necessarily a setter but that is usually what it is.

`@Required` methods are processed by `RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` which states that

> This neatly pushes responsibility for such checking onto the container
>   (where it arguably belongs), and obviates the need (in part) for a
>   developer to code a method that simply checks that all required
>   properties have actually been set.

So the purpose is to guarantee that properties are set by checking if the **container** has actually invoked the method.

The typical pattern is

```
class Foo {
    private String value;
    @Required
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

with a bean definition

```
<bean class="Foo" id="fooBean">
    <property name="value" value="some value"/>
</bean>
```

If you had not added the `<property>`, the container would complain and throw exceptions, just like it does with your configuration

```
<bean id='stu' class='com.bean.StudentAuto' >
</bean>
```

Here, the container is not using the `@Required` method to set the property. It is using reflection on the `Field` directly because of `@Autowired`. Therefore the `@Required` annotation is not validated.

Comment: Could you please tell how to set the **Required** annotated parameters from **Bean** annotated method in **Configuration** annotated java class **(the java way equivalent to given solution)**. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**1. DOC:**

> **[@Required](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-required-annotation)**
>
> This annotation simply indicates that the affected bean property must be populated at configuration time, through `an explicit property value in a bean definition` or through `autowiring`.

**2. Please pay attention:**
`@Required` annotation is used for validation checking, not for dependency injection.

**3. A way to fix:**
As the error log shows: `Property 'city' is required for bean 'stu'`. So, you should add a propery tag into the `stu` bean - inject `city` ***manually***:

```
<bean id="stu" class="com.bean.StudentAuto">
    <property name="city" value="London"/>
</bean>
```